# JavaScript to detect if the parent frame is of the same origin?

Tags: javascript, browser, same-origin-policy

I'm looking for a cross-browser way to detect whether the parent frame is the same origin as my frame, preferably without printing warnings on the JavaScript error console.

The following seems to work but I'd like to avoid printing errors to the console (at least Safari and Chrome do when accessing location.href on the parent frame. Firefox throws an exception which can be caught):

```
function parentIsSameOrigin() {
    var result = true;
    try {
        result = window.parent.location.href !== undefined;
    } catch (e) {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I would do something like:

```
var sameOrigin;
try
{
    sameOrigin = window.parent.location.host == window.location.host;
}
catch (e)
{
    sameOrigin = false;
}
return sameOrigin;
```

Comment: I sadly spent some hours with this solution, only to find out this doesn't work for WebKit where the same origin Error is uncathable.

Do NOT use this solution.

Comment: @Spork, I do not have this issue using a recent Chrome (43). Can you tell on which browser/version does this issue occur please?

Answer (score 1):

I use this method to tell if an iframe contains local content,

but you can pass it window.top from the iframe just as well

```
function islocal(win){
var H=location.href,
    local= H.substring(0, H.indexOf(location.pathname));
    try{
        win=win.document;
        return win && win.URL && win.URL.indexOf(local)== 0;
    }
    catch(er){
        return false
    }
}
```

//test case alert(islocal(window.top))

Comment: This is not cross browser since [`window.URL` support varies greatly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/URL)

Comment: The only browsers not supporting window.URL are end-of-life.  So unless you are JQuery....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function parentIsSameOrigin()
{
    var result = true;
    if (window.parent)
    {
        result = Boolean
        (
            // more precise modifications needed here
            window.this.location.href.indexOf(window.parent.location.href) == 0
        );
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: There seems to be an extra "this" in there, but even if I remove it I get a warning. Simply accessing `window.parent.location.href` triggers it.

Comment: This will also still give a same origin exception.